# Adding to ambient typescript declarations

Tags: typescript, kendo-ui, typescript-typings

I am using the Kendo.web.d.ts file. It looks something like this:

```
declare namespace kendo.ui {
  interface GridColumnCommandItem {
    name?: string;
    click?: Function;
    //etc
  }
}
```

Because the declaration from Kendo is not complete, I need to add to it. So I have created another file called kendo.fixes.d.ts.

```
declare namespace kendo.ui {
  interface GridColumnCommandItem {
    imageClass?: string;
  }
}
```

When I go to use the interface, I get an error saying imageClass is not part of the GridColumnCommandItem:

```
/// <reference path="../../vendor/typings/kendo/kendo.web.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/kendo/kendo.fixes.d.ts" />
import {OtherClass} from './OtherClass';

class MyClass {

    public getDeleteCol(): kendo.ui.GridColumnCommandItem {
        const col: kendo.ui.GridColumnCommandItem = {
            name: 'Delete',
            imageClass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign'
        };
        return col;
    }
}
```

Error:(361, 13) TS2322:Type '{ name: string; imageClass: string; }' is not assignable to type 'GridColumnCommandItem'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'imageClass' does not exist in type 'GridColumnCommandItem'.

It seems that my fixes file is being ignored? How can I tell typescript about kendo's missing functionality?

Comment: Where did you get `kendo.web.d.ts` file from?  There is no such file on [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/kendo-ui), and the [one found on github somewere](https://github.com/barbagallo/KendoUIWeb/blob/master/typescript/kendo.web.d.ts) has `declare module kendo`, not `declare namespace`.

Comment: npm install --save-dev @types/kendo-ui